# diff between public and not function

Tags: php, oop, function, scope, public

what is the different between

```
public function something()
{

}
```

and

```
function something()
{

}
```

any explaination? which more better?

Comment: it is exacly the same.by default it is public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP/4 did not implement [visibility](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) yet. When it was added in PHP/5, a missing visibility keyword was made synonym of `public` so existing code would not break.

If it's legacy code, my advice is to leave it as is until you have the chance to review the code and pick an adequate visibility. If it's new code, you should make it explicit.